# Group data frame row by consecutive value in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to group a data frame by consecutive value in a row.
So for example, given this data frame:

```
tibble( time = c(1,2,3,4,5,10,11,20,30,31,32,40) )
```

I want to have a grouping column like:

```
tibble( time = c(1,2,3,4,5,10,11,20,30,31,32,40), group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5) )
```

What's a tidyverse (or base R) way to get the column group as explained?

Comment: Just skip the `split` part in the linked post. Or use the convenience function `collapse::seqid`. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `diff` on the adjacent values of 'time', check if the difference is not equal to 1, then change the logical vector to numeric index by taking the cumulative sum  (`cumsum`) so that there is an increment of 1 at each TRUE value

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(time) != 1)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
    time   grp
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     2     1
 3     3     1
 4     4     1
 5     5     1
 6    10     2
 7    11     2
 8    20     3
 9    30     4
10    31     4
11    32     4
12    40     5
```

Answer (score 2):

We could it this way:

```
df %>%
    arrange(time) %>%
    group_by(grp = (time  %/% 10)+1)
```

```
 time group
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1
 2     2     1
 3     3     1
 4     4     1
 5     5     1
 6    10     2
 7    11     2
 8    20     3
 9    30     4
10    31     4
11    32     4
12    40     5
```

Comment: My bad, I put consecutive in the same about ten, but this is not a generic case. So I've to reject your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(grp = accumulate(2:nrow(df), .init = 1, 
                          ~ if(time[.y] - time[.y - 1] == 1) {
                            .x 
                          } else {
                            .x + 1
                          }))

# A tibble: 12 x 2
    time   grp
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1
 2     2     1
 3     3     1
 4     4     1
 5     5     1
 6    10     2
 7    11     2
 8    20     3
 9    30     4
10    31     4
11    32     4
12    40     5
```